# Grafana connection to databricks SQL warehouse

Tags: json, databricks, grafana

I want to have my databricks SQL as my grafana data source. I am trying to use the JSON API to connect it, however it won't work for me. I know there's a plugin for it but its enterprise version and I couldn't get that.